# Ant Design Form - onAfterChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, antd

I've created a form with antd that outputs the form values to the console whenever a field has changed by using the `onValuesChange` function on a `Form`.

My issue is that `Slider` components call this `onValuesChange` function whilst dragging the slider and I'd like it to instead be at `onmouseup`.

I'm aware that the `onAfterChange` event of a slider only fires `onmouseup` but I'm not sure how to make `onValuesChange` use `onAfterChange` instead of `onChange`. Can anyone offer advice on this?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Slider } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

class UnwrappedMyForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <Form>
                <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator(`field1`, {})(
                            <Slider range defaultValue={[0, 100]} />
                    )}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator(`field2`, {})(
                            <Slider range defaultValue={[0, 100]} />
                    )}
                </FormItem>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

const MyForm = Form.create({
    onValuesChange(props, changedValues, allValues) {
        console.log(allValues);
    }
})(UnwrappedMyForm);

export default MyForm;
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/z2ppnop8x

Answer (score 0):

you should never do it! if I will know the purpose I can help you better,

but this will work for you:

```
render() {
    const { form, errorMessage } = this.props;
    const { getFieldDecorator, setFieldsValue } = form;

    return (
      <Form>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator(`slider`, {})(
            <div>
              <Slider onAfterChange={wantedValues => setFieldsValue({ slider: wantedValues })} range />
            </div>,
          )}
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
export default Form.create({
  onValuesChange(props, changedValues, allValues) {
    console.log('on change', allValues);
  },
```

The value of the slider and the value of the slider field is separate and you are updating the field value manualy

Comment: Thanks for your help @U.Rush. So the example you gave solves the issue but you recommend to never do it like this - is that right? The reason for my question is that I make an Ajax call in onValuesChange so would like it to just make one call on release of the mouse rather than lots of requests whilst the slider is being dragged

Comment: so you can solve that issue in two ways
option 1 filter the onChange result and call the Ajax request just when it has the final result (use somthing like debounce or throttle. These wrapers functions call to action just after period of time from the last call.)
Explain on the functions: `https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/debounce-and-throttle-in-real-life-scenarios-1cc7e2e38c68`
Use lodash  library and don't implement it by your self it will make it easier for you.

Comment: option 2 ) use 'submit' button- when the user press 'save' button in the modal the Ajax request sent or a call to action to propagate the desired result to the modal container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue and maybe this is a simpler approach:

The keypoint is to maintain an internal state for this slider component and send the wanted value through `onChange` during `onAfterChange`.

```js
const MouseUpSlider = ({ value, onChange, ...rest }) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(value)

  return (
    <Slider
      value={val}
      onAfterChange={(value) => onChange(value)}
      onChange={(value) => setVal(value)}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```