# Ant-design Form OnAfterchange Handler - OnValuesChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

My form has 50 of fields, therefore I'm using `onValuesChange` to detect change in any element of the form.

> However there is a delay of one character typing (one state change i.e. user action)
>
> Can we configure onValuesChanged, to invoke the handler after
>   execution?

```
class MyInfoForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.AntFormComponent = Form.create({
            onValuesChange: props.onValuesChange
        })(MyInfo); <--//**50 fields inside `MyInfo` separate Component.
    }

    render() {
        const Comp = this.AntFormComponent;
        return <>{<Comp {...this.props} />}</>;
    }
}
export default props => <MyInfoForm {...props} />;
MyInfoForm.propTypes = {
    onValuesChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Answer in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047722/ant-design-form-onafterchange-handler) tells to use onAfterChange in each element that means code repetition 50 times.

Comment: why do you need to handle onValuesChange, you can let the form handle by itself and get the end result on submit.
if the reason is to check if the form is dirty, I suggest using a dedicated form library like formik, react-final-form.. etc

Comment: @Tubc, Even before form is submitted, If all fields are valid, I have to indicate a summary message, saying 'well done' Unfortunately I'm not in command to change library.

Comment: I understand your use-case and the form library I suggested is made for that. it only deal with the form logic, you can keep using ant design components. otherwise you have to do it by yourself, meaning code repetition/bugs etc

Comment: I don't understand what does "there is a delay of one character typing" means, any producible example?